# Error in set up procedure of openerp server

Tags: python, odoo

When i run this command

```
root@wa3pc11:/# openerp-server
```

gets an error

Error occur when starting the server daemon: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using two instances of OpenERP, then the following will do the magic:

1. Type
                      sudo netstat -anpt

in terminal. This will list the active processes and the port numbers they are using.

1. Find the process which uses the port number of OpenERP and note the pid(process id) of that process.
2. Then type

   ```
               ps aux | grep openerp
   ```

and verify the pid of that process.

1. Kill the process which uses the port number of OpenERP(if any) by the following command in terminal.

   ```
                sudo kill -9 pid
   ```

where pid is the process id. For example if 1234 is the pid you should enter

```
                 sudo kill -9 1234
```

in terminal.

1. Then remove the pid of OpenERP server from /var/run/openerp by the following.

   ```
               sudo rm /var/run/openerp-server.pid
   ```
2. Restart the openerp-server and it's done.

   ```
               sudo /etc/init.d/openerp-server restart
   ```